# Cannot send tokens on NEAR protocol testnet

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm following this snippet: https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#send-tokens to try to send some NEAR tokens but got this error (I had 200 NEAR token when created an account on testnet as default):

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Access Key {account_id}:{public_key} does not have enough balance 0.25 for transaction costing 1.0000453060601875
```

While connecting to the wallet from my dApp, I got a limited permission as `This does not allow the app to transfer tokens`

[image]

So, is this limited permission caused the above issue of `sendMoney`? and how I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help!